# Coloring a ParametricPlot3D with a custom color function

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

I am plotting a trajectory $\left(x(t),y(t),z(t)\right)$ as a ParametricPlot3D and want to assign the value of another function $C(x,y,z)$ as the color this parametric plot at point $\left(x,y,z\right)$.

As an example I tried doing

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t, 2 t, 3 t}, {t, -10, 10},PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.05],ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", {100, 0}}, #1^2] &)]
```

Where I was thinking my coloring function was $C(x,y,z)=x^2$

so it's value would be between 0 and 100 but when I try running the code I seem to be using the wrong coloring function.
[image: plot]

What Color function should I use so that for each point of the parametric plot $\left(x(t),y(t),z(t)\right)$ as the color $C\left(x(t),y(t),z(t)\right)$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

Comment: Looks like that solves the problem. Thanks!